# Control cheap Xiaomi Outlets with Harmony

Tags: smart-home, smart-plugs, logitech-harmony

I want to know how I can control these cheap Xiaomi outlets with the outlet buttons on my harmony companion remote. These outlets are way cheaper than anything Harmony supports natively.

Is there an emulator that can emulate these outlets as something else?

Here's what they look [like](https://www.ebay.com.au/itm/Xiaomi-Wireless-Home-Smart-Socket-Outlet-App-Remote-Control-Switch-AU-Plug-/131834406202).
Does anyone have any suggestions. Should I buy these outlets?

Comment: What do you mean "as something else"?

Comment: As emulated hue through home assistant. Would this work?